# Best practice for setting package options through class options?

Tags: documentclass-writing, package-options, class-options

I want to process my class options so as to create a (potentially long) options list for package(s) I'm loading, e.g.

```
% set default package options here somehow
\DeclareOption{myvariant}{
    % set a bunch of alternative options overriding the default
}

\RequirePackage[some kind of magic should go here]{mypackage}
```

Specifically, I thought maybe I should be using PassOptionsToClass, but then - how do I prevent the default action?

Right now I'm doing something else, and kind of ugly, which relies on my specific package of interest (`geometry`) allowing doing everything with a command rather than a package option:

```
\newcommand{\iitcs@geometry{\geometry{key=val,key2=val2}}
\DeclareOption{myopt}{
 \renewcommand{\iitcs@geometry{\geometry{key=val3,key3=val4}}
}
%...
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\iitcs@geometry
```

(edit) I'll emphasize that I'd like a solution for the case I have no choice but to provide the right package options, with no flexibility like with `geometry'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\geometry` and options therein multiple times. So for this application I suggest something like

```
\DeclareOption{myopt}{%
  \AtEndOfPackage{\geometry{paperwidth=3cm,paperheight=9cm}}}

\ProcessOptions\relax
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=12cm,paperheight=12cm} % default
```

In more general cases it may be more difficult, because options are executed in the order they are listed in the package, when it calls `\ProcessOptions`.

So if `packageB.sty` declares `x` and `nox` in this order (later using `\ProcessOptions`, not `\ProcessOptions*`) and you say in `packageA.sty`

```
\DeclareOption{x}{\PassOptionsToPackage{x}{packageB}}
\DeclareOption{nox}{\PassOptionsToPackage{nox}{packageB}}

\ExecuteOptions{nox}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\RequirePackage{packageB}
```

then `nox` will be executed last by `packageB` no matter if you call `packageA` with the `x` option.

So a more precise answer depends on "real world" situations.

Comment: Umm, won't the `\AtEndOfPackage` be executed before the \geometry command below? Or maybe I'm missing its semantics. Also, and more importantly, I'm interested in a general approach, so let's assume I have to load the package with the proper options rather than a command later on. Have edited my question to clarify that.

Comment: No, `\AtEndOfPackage` code is executed when LaTeX ends reading the `.sty` file, just prior returning to read the calling file. `\ProcessOptions` will simply set the token list for `\AtEndOfPackage`.

Comment: How will it know which sty to exacute after? Also, in your second example, won't nox be executed first rather than last, due to the `\ExecuteOption{nox}`? Finally, I'm more interested in one-option-to-many rather than one-option-to-one.